# Disable <span> button child click

Tags: jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, click

My button:

```
<span class="btn btn-default emailAddressEdit" email_address_id="55924"> 
  <i class="icon-edit"></i>
  <span>Edit</span>
</span>
```

My event binding in Backbone:

```
Events : {
  "click .emailAddressEdit" : "emailAddressEditClick",
}
```

The thing is: If I click the icon or the inner SPAN, it doesn't pass me the email_address_id attribute. What is an elegant way to fire the click from the parent?

**EDIT / Answer**

The trick is the use `event.currentTarget` in the event handler.

Comment: Please show source `emailAddressEditClick`

Comment: Can you pass/read `event` object in `emailAddressEditClick` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with backbone events before, but in jQuery event handlers `this` is a reference to the element that matches the selector, not necessarily the element that was clicked. In that case, you could so something like the following:

```
function emailAddressEditClick() {
    var emailAddressId = $(this).attr('email_address_id');
    //do something with ID here
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with backbone but this should be the answer as it's standard for DOM events. `this` refers to the object listening for events, `event.target` refers to the object the event originally fired on (and may have bubbled up from).

Comment: I did not know that, thanks! However, in backbone, "this" referrs to my "view" instance that is creating the listener. I now use $(evt.currentTarget) and is works like a charm!

Comment: For future readers: `event.currentTarget` is a jQuery extension, specifically equivalent to the native `this` of an unbound event listener function: http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Answer (score 2):

You could do the below:

**HTML**

```
<span class="btn btn-default emailAddressEdit" data-email_address_id="55924"> 
     <i class="icon-edit"></i>
     <span>Edit</span>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
var emailAddressEditClick = function()
{
    var emailAddressId = $(this).closest('btn').data('email_address_id');
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user clicks the emailAddressEdit, but not on one of the children?

Comment: Thank you Thanassis_K, however, this would mean adding code for every button. It's not the elegant solution I'd like.

Comment: "this", in the case of a backbone event binding, is the view-instance, not the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain vanilla JavaScript solution you can do something like this:

```
<span class="btn btn-default emailAddressEdit" email_address_id="55924" onclick="emailAddressEditClick(this);"> 
   <i class="icon-edit"></i>
   <span>Edit</span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function emailAddressEditClick(elem) {
        alert(elem.getAttribute("email_address_id") || elem.parentElement.getAttribute("email_address_id"))
    }

</script>
```

Basically it passes clicked element to the function, and the function displays "email_address_id" from the element itself (if it has it) or from the parent (if it doesn't)